# Showing a basis for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Given the polynomials

P1 $(x)$ = $2 + x - x^2 - 2x^3$

P2 $(x)$ = $1 + x + 2x^2 + x^3$

P3 $(x)$ = $1 - x -x^2 + 2x^3$

P4 $(x)$ = $1 + x^2 + 2x^3$

Show that the set $S$ = (P1 $(x)$, P2 $(x)$, P3 $(x)$, P4 $(x)$) is a basis of $P^3$.

Now, I understand that to be a basis it has to be linearly independent and span $P^3$.

It spans $P^3$ as $P^3 = span(1, x, x^2, x^3)$ and each of the polynomials can be written in that form.

For linear independence I used the formula K1P1 + K2P2 + K3P3 + K4P4 = $0$ and found the result

$2$K1 + K2 + K3 + K4 = $0$

K1 + K2 - K3     = $0$

-K1 + $2$K2 - K3 + K4  = $0$

$-2$K1 + K2 + $2$K3 + $2$K4 = $0$

I know it can be solved directly or the determinant of the coefficient matrix can be used, however that gave a result of $-1$. I know you can use symbols like $r, s, t$ to solve directly but honestly I don't understand how that works. Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: If the determinant of the coefficient matrix is $-1$, then in particular it is not zero. That means the system of equations has a unique solution. But $K_1 = K_2=K_3=K_4=0$ is a solution, so it must be the only one.

Comment: Your argument to show that it spans is wrong. You have to show that each of the polynomials $1,x,x^2,x^3$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$; what you have stated is the other way around, that each of $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ can be expressed as a linear combination of  $1,x,x^2,x^3$.

Comment: Anyway, this type of question has been asked and answered a dozen times on this website. I encourage you to do a search to find an earlier question where the methods are presented in detail.

Comment: Any thoughts on answer and/or comments, Duncan?

Comment: I was more looking at ways to solve the linear independence for the system created. I wonder if perhaps using Cramer's rule would help.

Comment: To prove something's a basis, you have to prove both spanning and independence, and as I pointed out you haven't actually proved spanning.

Comment: Anyway, as you found the determinant was not zero, that shows the system has only the trivial solution $K_1=K_2=K_3=K_4=0$, which shows the polynomials are linearly independent (this was actually the content of the very first comment on the question). No need for Cramer here.

Comment: Are you still here, Duncan?

Comment: So when you find a determinant and it equals 0 it means it is linearly independent, and if it isn't 0 then only the K values = 0 still make it linearly independent?

Comment: And to show the span, I would need to show that they form a linear combination?

Comment: As астон вілла тереса лисбон wrote, and as I wrote, if the determinant is **Not** zero, then you have linear independence (because it means that the only way to get zero as a linear combination is to take all coefficients zero, which is the definition of linear independence). If the determinant *is* zero, then you can get zero as a linear combination with nonzero coefficients, so you *don't* have linear independence.

Comment: "And to show the span, I would need to show that they form a linear combination?" Duncan, you're not expressing yourself clearly. What does "they" refer to? What does it mean, "they form a linear combination"? You'll never get anywhere at university-level mathematics if you can't use the vocabulary accurately and correctly. To show that $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ is a spanning set, you have to do what I wrote in my first comment on your question; you have to show that each of the polynomials $1,x,x^2,x^3$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$.

Comment: Did that help, Duncan?

Comment: Gone away again, Duncan?

Comment: Ok, so it does form a basis then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have shown that it spans $P^3$. It remains to show that $S $ is linearly independent.
consider the  matrix generated by tuples $(2,1,-1,-2)$,$(1,1,2,1)$,$(1,-1,-1,2)$,$(1,0,1,2)$:

\begin{bmatrix}2&1&-1&-2\\1&1&2&1\\1&-1&-1&2\\1&0&1&2\end{bmatrix}.
If  the determinant of above matrix is zero then linearly dependent otherwise independent.

Comment: Right so I didn't need to apply the formula for K, but take the determinant of the original matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by "the formula for $K$", Duncan?

Comment: K is the formula for linear independence

Comment: You're not making sense, Duncan. You're talikng about the formula for the formula for linear independence? Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.